# SQL Azure Platform Upgrade Causes Persistent Issues

Tags: azure-sql-database

While running a script to create a new table on our production Business Critical SQL DB last night, we ran into an issue with background processes consuming 100% of the CPU on our server, essentially bricking our server by not being able to login to it. Our only course of action was to force a scaling operation which immediately released the background processes and allowed traffic back to the database while the scale was in operations. Database CPU utilization preceding the time of adding the table was approximately 20%.

We had seen an 'upgrade' by Azure in the activity log a day previous with this message

*"Your database was unavailable due to planned maintenance. To ensure service quality and security, we roll out upgrades on a monthly schedule. Upgrade payload may include OS patches and security fixes, new and updated SQL product features, and repairs. Planned maintenance events are almost always short, lasting at most a few seconds. Currently, Azure shows the downtime for your SQL database resource at a one-minute granularity. The actual downtime is likely less than a minute – average is 2s. Please also note the outage window may be shifted by around 5 minutes."*

This was followed by several health events following the upgrade which were are marked as resolved so we didn't pursue any further.

Our theory is the primary database somehow locked up while trying to push our sql changes to the other replicas in the availability zone. Does this make sense? Has anyone else seen this sort of behavior?

Added a table to a production database, database would contain the new table and script would be complete.

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's about Azure SQL Databases; that is a serverless solution.